# jQuery - Loop through Divs and set heights dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of DIVs which each have 2 child DIVs with different heights as per the content within them. I am looking to use jQuery to loop through the set of parent divs, to inspect the children divs and set the shorter of the 2 children divs to be the same height as the taller one... Possible?

So parent div always has the class "jointeamPeepWrapper", then the children DIVS can be easily identified by the class "blockLHS" for the first and "blockRHS" for the 2nd one....

HTML structure is:

```
<div class="aboutPeepsWrapper jointeamPeepWrapper">
  <div class="aboutPeepsPhotoWrapperLHS wideBlock blockLHS"><img src="biogPhoto.jpg"></div>
  <div class="aboutPeepsTextWrapperRHS greenBG smallBlock blockRHS">
    <div class="aboutPeepsTextInner">
      <h4>Aim high</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aboutPeepsWrapper jointeamPeepWrapper">
  <div class="aboutPeepsTextWrapperLHS halfBlock orangeBG blockLHS">
    <div class="aboutPeepsTextInner">
      <h4>Just for fun</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutPeepsPhotoWrapperRHS halfBlock blockRHS"><img src="biogPhoto2.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="aboutPeepsWrapper jointeamPeepWrapper">
  <div class="aboutPeepsPhotoWrapperLHS wideBlock blockLHS"><img src="biogPhoto3.jpg"></div>
  <div class="aboutPeepsTextWrapperRHS greenBG smallBlock blockRHS">
    <div class="aboutPeepsTextInner">
      <h4>Talks &amp; events</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this *all the time*!

```
$(".jointeamPeepWrapper").each(function(){
    var tallestHeight = 0;
    $(this).children("div").each(function(){
        $(this).outerHeight("auto");
        if(parseInt($(this).outerHeight(true)) > tallestHeight){
            tallestHeight = parseInt($(this).outerHeight(true));
        }
    });
    $(this).children("div").outerHeight(tallestHeight);
});
```

EDIT:  Will run on window resize:

```
function fixPeepHeight(){
    $(".jointeamPeepWrapper").each(function(){
        var tallestHeight = 0;
        $(this).children("div").each(function(){
            $(this).outerHeight("auto");
            if(parseInt($(this).outerHeight()) > tallestHeight){
                tallestHeight = parseInt($(this).outerHeight());
            }
        });
        $(this).children("div").outerHeight(tallestHeight);
    });    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  fixPeepHeight();
  $(window).smartresize(function () {      
      fixPeepHeight();
  });
});


/*! Smart Resize */
(function ($, sr) {

    // debouncing function from John Hann
    // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
    var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
        var timeout;

        return function debounced() {
            var obj = this, args = arguments;
            function delayed() {
                if (!execAsap)
                    func.apply(obj, args);
                timeout = null;
            };

            if (timeout)
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            else if (execAsap)
                func.apply(obj, args);

            timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
        };
    }
    // smartresize
    jQuery.fn[sr] = function (fn) { return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery, 'smartresize');
/* /Smart Resize */
```

Comment: You loop over the parent divs, instead of child.

Comment: Ah, you're right, didn't read closely enough.  Check my edit.

Comment: Hi Sean - thanks for the reply - but it looks like you are setting the parent div height here... ?

Comment: Your change assumes that the left hand side is always larger than the right hand side.  Parsing as integer actually is important sometimes because some browsers (Firefox especially) screw up the floating point heights.  I've run into that problem before, so I just make them integers.  I don't need a fraction of a pixel!

Comment: Sean - this does not seem to respond when I call the function on page resize... any reason ?

Comment: It will run once only.  I've updated the answer to run every time the page resizes, but I highly recommend you use a "debounce" function (in the answer)

Comment: I am wrapping your code in  a function and calling it on page load and then also $(window).resize(function() { joinTeamBlocks(); });

Comment: Looks flawed when the elements have any margin... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meOdMq

Comment: No, they're the same height, as per the OP's question.  They aren't lined up vertically, but that wasn't a requirement in the OP's question.  That's a different matter entirely.

Comment: @dubbs try that new edit, I wrapped the page resize binding in the `$(document).ready()` function to allow the DOM to fully load so the functions are available.

Comment: It's simply incorrect in any circumstance. It will set the new size to include any margin. Vertical alignment is irrelevant in the example - the elements should be 200px high and they're both 300px.

Comment: Sean - no it doesn't work - as the height values are hard coded in your code - so when you resize - the values never change - despite the height of the content in the children divs making the heights change...

Comment: When the page first loads, it sets the height of the child div

Comment: Ah, I see, ok, lemme fix it.

Comment: K, try that, I set the heights to "auto" before testing their heights, they should grow now.

Comment: If "auto" doesn't work, change it to `""` in that spot, it will clear the inline height attribute.

Comment: Seems unfair that I answered your question, you accepted it, then you changed your question and unaccepted my answer...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90638/discussion-between-seankendle-and-dubbs).

Comment: Sean, I un-accepted the answer as it did not work - that's all - your thinking helped me resolve this issue as per my coded answer below ;) So many thanks for that. I have re-accepted your answer btw for what its worth ;)

Comment: You could easily extend this to accept optional parameters to the `fixPeepHeights()` function, as well, and use it over and over again on the same site by passing in the class names of the target elements.  You'd probably want to change the name of the function, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this script should work exactly for your scenario

```
$('.jointeamPeepWrapper').each(function () {
    var blockLHS = $(this).children('.blockLHS');
    var blockRHS = $(this).children('.blockRHS');
    if (blockLHS.height() > blockRHS.height())
        blockRHS.height(blockLHS.height());
    else
        blockLHS.height(blockRHS.height());
});
```

Comment: Any chance of it work inside a function called on window resize?

Comment: (Did I hallucinate? Didn't you accept someone else's answer before?) Anyway, that's because the heights are already set when the window resizes, let me come up with something to reset them.

Comment: Ah well I see I didn't hallucinate, @SeanKendle is right it's kinda rude to unaccept his answer. As he's working on this for you I'll leave him to it, his solution was probably more thourough than mine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. Use a jQuery selector which matches the DIVs you want to update. You'll probably need to run `each` on the matched DIVs twice, once to get the max height and second to update the height of the DIVs to the max height.
Also, to make it easier to identify the child DIVs, add the same class name to each one. DIVs can have multiple classes!

Something like this:

```
var nodes = $(#parent).find('.child');
int maxHeight = 0;
nodes.each(function() { Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).css('height')); });
nodes.each(function() { $(this).css('height', maxHeight)); });
```